# Elm - do not escape html string

Tags: html, escaping, elm

The documentation of ELM Html clearly states that

> It will escape the string so that it appears exactly as you specify

How should I do then if I want to escape the string, instead?

For example, suppose I have the string `"&#8220;"`, how could I render it as `“`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way around that limitation is to use unicode characters instead of escaping. That is, your rendered HTML will actually contain the unicode `“` rather than the html-escaped value of `&#8220;`

[See this related discussion](https://github.com/evancz/elm-html/issues/54).

Comment: That could be a possibility. Then the question becomes: is there a function  in ELM that do such a conversion? I'm fetching the string from an API I'm not controlling, so I can't modify the original string

Comment: [`Char.fromCode 8220`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Char#fromCode) will give you that character for the digit 8220. For non-digit escapes (e.g. `&amp;`) you will have to do a mapping function similar to [what is described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971362/how-can-i-get-special-characters-using-elm-html-module#answer-33981403).

Comment: Thank you! As far as you know, is there some function that I could use to parse a string and make such a conversion?

Comment: None that I currently know of besides the examples I linked. It sure would be nice to have VirtualDom support html escaping in the future though! This is definitely a sore spot!

Comment: The referenced link, ["See this related discussion,"](https://github.com/evancz/elm-html/issues/54) has rotted.

Answer (score 4):

I recently created an [Elm package](https://github.com/jasonmahr/html-escape-sequences/) that solves this. If you use `text' "&#8220;"` it'll render “ instead of the escape code. Also works with `"&ldquo;"`, `"&OpenCurlyDoubleQuote;"`, and the hex entity `"&#x201C;"`. Should work when fetching from an API. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.

Comment: thanks, but I actually already built my own package that does the same thing... http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/marcosh/elm-html-to-unicode/1.0.0/